# Get tab status using pyforms

Tags: pyforms

I'm working with pyforms to create a tab widget and I want to get and set the current active tab. Consider this example:

```
self.formset = [{ 
    'Person A': ['_firstname', '_lastname'],
    'Person B': ['_firstname', '_lastname'] }]
```

so we get 2 tabs `Person A` and `Person B`. If I switch between them I would like to be informed with something similar to PyQt function `currentIndex()`. So far I havn't been able to find a method in the pyforms documentation, is there a way to accomplish this just using pyforms?

Answer (score 1):

The main issue in getting or setting the current index of your tab widget is to get access to the QTabWidget created by pyforms when the layout is generated. Once you have access to it, you simply call the *setCurrentIndex(int)/currentIndex()* of the widget.
A (dirty) quick fix to this is to modify the `BaseWidget.py` located in the pyforms module files which can be `<VIRTUALENV_DIR>/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyforms/gui` when using virtualenv.

```
def generate_tabs(self, formsetdict):
    """
    Generate QTabWidget for the module form
    @param formset: Tab form configuration
    @type formset: dict
    """
    tabs = QTabWidget(self)
    for key, item in sorted(formsetdict.items()):
        ctrl = self.generate_panel(item)
        tabs.addTab(ctrl, key[key.find(':') + 1:])
    self.tabs = tabs
    return tabs
```

Note the additional :

```
self.tabs = tabs
```

Then in the code of your widget/app (subclass of BasicWidget) :

```
>>> _t = self.tabs
>>> _t.setCurrentIndex(3) # activate the 4th tab
>>> print(_t.currentIndex())
3
```